# nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard() does not work

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter, frame

When I run

```py
nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard()
nfl_frame
```

jupyter notebook shows me just a link from Wikipedia.
Normally, I want to get a table win and loss from the NFL league.
What should I have done or do?

Comment: try to use pandas [read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

Comment: yess it works. I changed the nfl_frame = pd.read_clipboard() in term of nfl_frame = pd.read_html('URL'). Thank you very much